# Disassembly of a C function

Tags: c, disassembly

I was trying to understand disassembled code of the following function.

```
void func(char *string) {
    printf("the string is %s\n",string);
}
```

The disassembled code is given below.

```
1) 0x080483e4 <+0>:     push   %ebp  
2) 0x080483e5 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp  
3) 0x080483e7 <+3>:     sub    $0x18,%esp  
4) 0x080483ea <+6>:     mov    $0x80484f0,%eax  
5) 0x080483ef <+11>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx  
6) 0x080483f2 <+14>:    mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)  
7) 0x080483f6 <+18>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)  
8) 0x080483f9 <+21>:    call   0x8048300 <printf@plt>
```

Could anyone tell me what lines 4-7 means (not the literal explanation). Also why  24 bytes are allocated on stack on line 3?

Comment: Are you familiar with how the stack works, e.g. when using `push`/`pop`?

Comment: I think I do know that

Comment: Then those lines are fairly simple - instead of `push`ing a value onto the stack, GCC manually moved the stack pointer and moved that value to the new top of the stack. Look at the "Arguments" section of [this article](http://codearcana.com/posts/2013/05/21/a-brief-introduction-to-x86-calling-conventions.html) , it explains this in some more detail. As for "why 24 bytes of stack", that's an internal decision by the compiler, which might be related to *stack alignment*, *stack canary* or just a random decision.

Comment: If I have understood correctly 1,2,3 sets up the stack frame. 5 and 6 moves (ebp+8) to (esp+4) (what is achieved by this?) and 0x80484f0 is in esp. I don't understand the significance of this address as it is not in my disassembled code (both of function and main).

Comment: Look at the source code. They are the parameters to printf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically what happens here:

```
4) 0x080483ea <+6> : mov $0x80484f0,%eax
```

Load the address of `"the string is %s\n"` into `eax`.

```
5) 0x080483ef <+11>: mov 0x8(%ebp),%edx
```

Move the argument `string` into `edx`.

```
6) 0x080483f2 <+14>: mov %edx,0x4(%esp)
```

Push the value of `edx` or `string` into the stack, second argument of `printf`

```
7) 0x080483f6 <+18>: mov %eax,(%esp)
```

Push the value of `eax` or `"the string is %s\n"` into the stack, first argument of `printf`, and then it will call `printf`.

`sub $0x18,%esp` is not necessary since the function has no local variables, gcc seems to like making extra space but honestly I don't know why.

Comment: Thank u for your answer. argument string means address of string here? Also regarding (sub $0x18,%esp), I think you are right as disassembly of different functions with arbitrary no of printf's showed that printf does not affect the no of variables reserved on the stack. Or It may have to do with stack canaries as @Dcoder pointed out

Comment: @user146297 As for string, yes, the address of string. This behavior of unnecessary `sub XXX, %esp` has been bothering me a long time, I couldn't find an answer for it.

Comment: Without the sub, the `mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)` will corrupt the stack.

Answer (score 1):

The stack is a continuous region of memory that starts at a higher address and ends at `esp`. Whenever you need your stack to grow, you subtract from `esp`. Every function can have a frame on the stack. It is the part of the stack that the function owns and is responsible for cleaning after it is done. It means, when the function starts it decreases `esp` to create its frame. When it ends it increases it back. `ebp` usually points to the beginning of your frame.

Initially this function pushs `ebp` to tha stack so that it can be stored when the function ends, sets `esp = ebp` to mark the begin of its frame and allocate 28 bytes. Why 28? For alignment. It already allocated 4 bytes for the `ebp`. 4 + 28 = 32.

The lines 4-7 will prepare the call to `printf`. It expects its arguments to be on the frame of the caller. When we read `mov 0x8(%ebp), %edx`, we are taking our argument `char* string` from the caller's frame. `printf` will do the same.

Note that your assembly is missing a `leave` and a `ret` instructions to clear the stack and return to the caller.